# Python–Inserting a Row in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel, insert, openpyxl

I've been searching for a solution for the last few days, and I never thought something so simple would be so near-impossible to find.

The projects I'm working on are stored in Excel files (from before I ever started programming), and I've been researching all the Python libraries I can find that support Excel.

All I want to do is insert an entire row, with or without its own content, just as one normally would be right-clicking in Excel and selecting 'insert'. Of course pandas has that function, but it works only on columns...no clue why they decided to create it that way.

When I use the "insert_rows" function in Openpxl, it completely destroys the documents. That's partly because I have a lot of merged and color-coded cells, I believe. So I'm just looking for alternative libraries to see if they have the same effect or not.

Does anyone know *any* library/function **besides Openpxl** that allows the simple task of inserting rows in Excel? Thanks in advance.

*Then I was prompted to answer what I tried, what I expected, and what happened. So here's my answer:*

I never really got the opportunity to try, because I never found complete steps that worked (other than Openpxl). When I saw suggestions on how to add rows, I originally thought it meant insert them. However, most sources just show how to add them at the end...not a big help.

Also, I came across Aspose [https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/working-with-rows-and-columns/]. Their entire page reminded me of one of those schemes that promises to make you rich fast and then ends up conning you. Nearly all the instructions they gave, even on opening files, led to errors and conflicts. You can try for yourself.

Also, I'll attach an image of what my spreadsheet looked like before (insert_rows w/ Openpxl) and after: you can see that inserting a row wiped out the color, unmerged all the cells, and deleted the content from many of them too.

[A clip of my originally created Excel Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5xyz.png)
[What happened to it after performing insert_rows with Openpxl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1sn4.png)

Comment: Xlwings will insert as Excel does, it uses Excel (needs Windows with Excel installed but does also work with MACOS with Excel tho some functions might not be so straight forward).

Comment: Thanks. I've got Windows 10. I think I installed Xlwings last night, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out this was the resolution: Xlwings was the one I finally got to cooperate. Now I just have to figure out how to make elaborate designs with it with merged cells of different colors.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, I came across Aspose [https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/working-with-rows-and-columns/]. Their entire page reminded me of one of those schemes that promises to make you rich fast and then ends up conning you. Nearly all the instructions they gave, even on opening files, led to errors and conflicts. You can try for yourself

You are trying to refer to/use Aspose.Cells.GridDesktop (.NET) component's documentation instead of using relevant APIs of [Aspose.Cells for Python via .NET](https://products.aspose.com/cells/python-net/) library. This library is used to manipulate Excel spreadsheet on python, so you should try it. It supports to insert_rows to Excel workbook via relevant APIs. You may download it using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/aspose-cells-python/) command:

Let us know if you find any issue working with the library.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I'm just getting back to these projects and I read your reponse. I did download it as you suggested. However, I don't see any real manuals or tutorials on that link. Are you able to provide updated instructions on how to insert a row? Thank you again.

Comment: You can see and browse the documentation (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/python-net/) for your reference. Also, see the document on inserting rows (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/inserting-and-deleting-rows-and-columns/).

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach:

```
import csv

#Load the existing file 

with open('XYZ.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    rows = list.(reader)
# In place of XYZ write your file name

# Specify the row index where you want to insert an empty row
row_index = 4
# In place of 4 write your desired row

# Enter an empty row at a specified index
rows.insert(row_index, [''] * len(rows[0]))

# Save the updated list as csv
with open('XYZ_updated.csv', 'w', newline = '') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks I'm trying, but it's not accepting:
rows = list.(reader)

Is that a typo/syntax issue?